# Row handle referred to a deleted row or a row marked for deletion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, vbscript, oledb

We have an old site that is giving us an error. It uses VBScript and the DB is SQL Server 2005.

Here is the code:

```
set oNotes = server.CreateObject("SCRIPTING.DICTIONARY")

openSQL "SELECT * FROM v_client_notes WHERE contact_id = " &_
    my_contactID & " ORDER BY client_notes_duedate ASC"

do while rs.eof = false
    set temp = server.CreateObject("SCRIPTING.DICTIONARY")
    load_rs temp, rs
    set oNotes(trim(rs("client_notes_id"))) = temp
    rs.movenext'error on this line
loop
```

Error:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e23'
>
> Row handle referred to a deleted row or a row marked for deletion.

This error does not happen all the time, just for record sets returned with certain contact_id's. Haven't been able to pinpoint the difference in the ones that work and the ones that don't.

As you can see the error happens on rs.movenext.

I have made sure that the table has a primary key (client_notes_id).

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT**

Here is the code for load_rs:

```
function load_rs(dict,Byref record)
    for each thing_record in record.fields
        dict(thing_record.name) = trim(thing_record.value)
    next
end function
```

Here is the update script. This is on a separate page that I post to (kinda AJAX style):

```
If request("client_notes") <> "" then
        client_notes_subject = request("client_notes_subject")
        client_notes_postedby = session("user") 
        client_notes_duedate = request("client_notes_duedate")
        if client_notes_duedate = "" then
            client_notes_duedate = NULL
        end if
        client_notes_date_entered = request("client_notes_date_entered")
        client_notes =  request("client_notes")
        if isnumeric(request("contactID")) then contact_id = request("contactID")
        if clientnotes_id="" then clientnotes_id="0"
        openSQL("SELECT * FROM client_notes WHERE client_notes_id=" & clientnotes_id)
        if rs.EOF then
            openSQL("SELECT newid()")
            client_notes_guid = rs(0)
            openSQL("select * from client_notes")
            rs.addnew
        else
            client_notes_guid = rs("guid")
            rs.update
        end if 

        rs("contact_id") = contact_id   
        rs("client_notes_subject") = client_notes_subject
        rs("client_notes_postedby") = session("user")
        'if client_notes_duedate <> Null then
        rs("client_notes_duedate") = client_notes_duedate 
        'end if
        rs("client_notes_date_entered") = client_notes_date_entered
        rs("client_notes") = client_notes
        rs("guid")=client_notes_guid
        rs.update

        'if client_notes_duedate = Null then 
        '   sqlSetNullnotes = "UPDATE client_notes SET client_notes_duedate = NULL WHERE client_notes_id=" & clientnotes_id
        '   opensql sqlSetNullnotes
        'end if

        next_due_date = request("next_due_date")
        if next_due_date = "" then
            next_due_date = NULL
        end if

        openSQL("SELECT * FROM " & MainContactsDB & " WHERE Contact_ID=" & contactID)
        rs("Last_Contact_Date") = client_notes_date_entered
        rs("Next_Contact_Date") = next_due_date
        rs.update
    end if
```

openSQL method:

```
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
function openSQL(SQLrs)
    if rs.state = 1 then rs.close
    'response.write sqlRS
    rs.Open SQLrs, conn, 3, 3
end function
```

Comment: What does `load_rs` do exactly? Also are you sure the line number is accurate?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, I updated my question with the code for load_rs. I have moved rs.movenext around to diff lines, including putting a condition around it, and the error line stays consistent with that code.

Comment: Since you say this is an old site, I assume it has worked fine until recently. So what has changed? Also, can you show us exactly what the function is doing (e.g. how does the `client_notes_id` column change)? I'm sure this could all be done with a simple `UPDATE` statement without the overhead of the recordset, the loop, the dictionary object - and it would probably be a quicker re-write than troubleshooting this legacy code...

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, thanks for replying. This issue has existed for a long time and this feature is now used more so the issue is finally hot enough to fix. The client_notes_id column shouldn't get changed, its the PK. Once set it shouldn't change. I'll update my question with the code that updates other properties of a note.

Comment: Does the `OpenSQL()` function send every recordset you open into the same `rs` object? That's probably bad. I feel for you... this is pretty awful code. And I've seen my share of complicated ASP forms.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, I updated my question with the openSQL function. Thanks for your sympathy, I spend most of my time in Java and Javascript, so this is nasty... lol.

Comment: Yeah I know it's not the answer you want to hear but I think the cleanest solution is to write a stored procedure and call it directly instead of dealing with all these various RS objects.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11599/discussion-between-dale-and-aaron-bertrand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I was able to solve this.

I am running the query against a view which joins 2 tables.

The problem was that sometimes a note was submitted without the user id so the join from one table to the other didn't work cause user id was null. I modified my query to the following:

```
"SELECT * FROM v_client_notes WHERE contact_id = " & my_contactID & " AND user_id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY client_notes_duedate ASC"
```

Now the error doesn't come back, it just excludes the notes that aren't assigned to someone. So now on to fixing why the note wasn't assigned to someone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You currently have this:

```
openSQL("SELECT * FROM " & MainContactsDB & " WHERE Contact_ID=" & contactID)
rs("Last_Contact_Date") = client_notes_date_entered
rs("Next_Contact_Date") = next_due_date
rs.update
```

Why is there no handling for `rs.EOF`? Perhaps this is where the code is dying?

Comment: "rs" at this point is a single note and the objects properties have been changed so I run an update, I'm not looping through it here. I can tinker around with that but I am not in a loop at that point. The problem doesn't happen when saving. The problem happens sometimes after I load some notes for a client and whatever it gets back from the DB it doesn't like.

Answer (score 0):

Should have the primary key in a table on which you would like to take an action, after that not any issue to update that table